# Show "folder-visible" exchange folders in powershell

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2016

I have some users that have "folder-visible" permissions to some shared mailboxes and subfolders. I am trying to build a ASP.NET web application (C#) that uses Exchange (2016) Powershell to get a treeview of the users visible folders. The thing is that I first need to know on which mailboxes the users has those folder-visible permissions.

As an admin-user I can type `Get-Mailbox` to see all mailboxes. After that I can perform `Get-MailboxFolderStatistics` to get all the subfolders of a specified mailbox. But as a standard user I only get my own mailbox (with `Get-Mailbox`).

Is there any chance to show all mailboxes + folders where a user has folder-visible permissions? -> I try to do this using the Exchange Powershell with the users credentials (no admin credentials!).

Thanks
Marius